# Font-Face dosnt work

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I use below code to load a font with @font-face statement.the font is in my dir yoo, but it dosn't work :

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'irseri’;
    src: url('irseri.ttf') format('truetype');
}

.about{
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family:irseri ;
    color: #9f9f9f;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

and this is my html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Mehdi page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
    <div class="text"><div class="image"></div>Some Title</div>
    <div class="about">Some Text<div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this bit a typo? `’;`

Comment: Is style external stylesheet or internal style?.

Comment: @vel its external stylesheet

Answer (score 1):

Try this code and make the font folder is correct. check once irseri.ttf font is in folder it may like     src: url('../fonts/irseri.ttf') format('truetype');

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'irseri';
    src: url('../irseri.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Comment: are you trying in localhost or in server.

Comment: add irseri.woff file and insert this code in font-face style.  url('fonts/irseri.woff') format("woff");

Comment: you copied the same typo.

Comment: @Mehdikhosravi Did you fix the typo yet? Because that might cause the issue.

Comment: what is typo ? how can i fix it ?

Comment: Change `font-family: 'irseri’;` to `font-family: 'irseri';`